# My android app crashing only on Samsung devices. How can I solve it?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, crash

I have an app on play store(my first app). My first version didn't crash. But when I released my second version it is crashing only on Samsung devices. I tested it on my no brand jelly bean device and on emulator and it is working perfectly. I have no Samsung devices. What can I do now?

I think it is crashing on launcher activity. My Launcher activity is Main. This is a splash screen. Code and error are provided below.

```
App Name : Rebel Poet Nazrul
package name : com.xplosive.rebelpoetnazrul
```

Copied from play store stack traces

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xplosive.rebelpoetnazrul/com.xplosive.rebelpoetnazrul.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1970)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.xplosive.rebelpoetnazrul.Main.onCreate(Main.java:56)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
... 11 more
```

Main.java

```
package com.xplosive.rebelpoetnazrul;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidbangladesh.bengali.support.BengaliUnicodeString;

public class Main extends Activity {

    MediaPlayer mp;

    TextView tvBanner, tv1;
    Typeface font;

    String banner, version, develop, developer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        // actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        // actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color
        // .parseColor("#6699FF")));
        // actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.GREEN));

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setTitle("বিদ্রোহী কবি নজরুল");

        initialize();

        banner = "বিদ্রোহী কবি নজরুল";
        version = "ভার্সন ২.০";
        develop = "Developed By";
        developer = "Xplo";

        int apiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

        if (apiVersion < 16) {
            BengaliUnicodeString.getBengaliUTF(Main.this, banner, tvBanner);
            BengaliUnicodeString.getBengaliUTF(Main.this, version, tv1);

        } else {
            tvBanner.setTypeface(font);
            tv1.setTypeface(font);

            tvBanner.setText(banner);
            tv1.setText(version);

        }

        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.startup);
        //mp = MediaPlayer.create(Main.this, R.raw.startup);

        mp.start();

        Thread timer = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(2000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                } finally {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this,
                            MainMenuActivity.class);

                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            };
        };

        timer.start();

    }

    private void initialize() {
        font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "solaimanlipinormal.ttf");
        tvBanner = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBanner);
        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

        super.onPause();
        mp.release();
        // mp.stop(); //this is not working
        finish();

    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#66CCFF"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvBanner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="বিদ্রোহী কবি নজরুল"
        android:textColor="@color/banner"
        android:textSize="35sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ভার্সন ২.০"
        android:textColor="@color/banner"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Developed By"
        android:textColor="@color/banner"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Xplo"
        android:textColor="@color/banner"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Crash Device list

```
Galaxy S DUOS (kyleopen)
Galaxy Grand duos (baffin)
Galaxy Tab3 8.0 (lt013g)
Galaxy Core (arubaslim)
nuclear-t03
Galaxy Note3 (hlte)
Galaxy S3 Mini (golden)
```

Comment: Whats on line 56 in OnCreate?

Comment: The older Samsung phones didn't seem to support India Fonts, see related: http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/tech/personal-tech/computing/Samsung-Galaxy-phones-to-now-support-9-Indian-languages/articleshow/21798412.cms

Comment: Please check out: mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.startup);

Comment: are u noticed about mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.startup); 56 line is commented out @wtsang02

Comment: same font was on 1.0 version but no crash. So, I think it is not about font. @donfuxx

Comment: What should i do? i didn't get you. @S.M_Emamian

Comment: Next time you should comment "//This is where its pointing at", and not just comment out the code. Because there are multiple places that you have commented out.

Comment: Don't support Samsung devices ;) JK

Comment: I didn't get you @KashifNazar